# detener un reloj javascript

Tags: javascript

he creado un reloj en javascript, que esta en un input, funciona perfecto el problema es que no puedo  detenerlo justo cuando  hago click en un botón  y  entro a otra función. adjunto codigo del script del reloj y luego el script de la otra función. Obtengo el valor en el input name=fechaout

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function mueveReloj(){
    momentoActual = new Date()
    dia = momentoActual.getDate()
    año = momentoActual.getFullYear()
    mes = momentoActual.getMonth()
    hora = momentoActual.getHours()
    minuto = momentoActual.getMinutes()
    segundo = momentoActual.getSeconds()

    if (segundo < 10 ){
      segundo = "0" + segundo
    }
     if (minuto < 10 ){
      minuto = "0" + minuto
    }
     if (mes < 10 ){
      mes = "0" + mes
    }
     if (hora < 10 ){
      hora = "0" + hora
    }



    horaImprimible = año + "-" + mes + "-" + dia + "  " + hora + ":" + minuto + ":" + segundo

    document.getElementById('fechaout').value = horaImprimible

    setTimeout("mueveReloj()",1000)
}
</script>///
```

/// codigo de la función donde debo detener el reloj no se como detener la función muevereloj()

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function agregar(id){

 $('#resultados1').show();
  $("#receptor_sal").attr('disabled','disabled');
  $("#destino").attr('disabled','disabled');
 var cant = document.getElementById('cantidad_'+id).value;
 var cants = document.getElementById('cants'+id).value;
 var receptor = document.getElementById('receptor_sal').value;
 var destino = document.getElementById('idestino').value;
 var idarea = document.getElementById('idarea').value;
 var iduser = document.getElementById('iduser').value;
 var comment = document.getElementById('comment').value;
 var fechaout= document.getElementById('fechaout').value;
 var control = setTimeout("mueveReloj()");
  cancelAnimationFrame(control);
</script>
```

Comment: Hola, Julio. Quizás podrías pasarte por las secciones **¿Cómo formulo una buena pregunta?** (https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y **¿Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo y verificable** (https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para completar tu pregunta y que te podamos ayudar mejor.

Answer (score 1):

En teoría `clearTimeout()` se usa para detener `setTimeout()` y `clearInterval()` para detener `setInterval()`, pero en la práctica, son intercambiables [documentacion MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout), aquí un ejemplo usando `clearInterval` para parar un `setTimeout`:

```js
let i = 0;
const tiempo = document.getElementById("tiempo");
const detener = document.getElementById("detener");

function mueveReloj(){
  tiempo.innerText = i++;
  const st = setTimeout(mueveReloj,1000);
  detener.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  clearInterval(st);//<-- st es el timer mismo
  })
}

mueveReloj();
```

```html
<div id="tiempo"></div>
<button id="detener">detener Reloj</button>
```

Ambas funciones reciben el id de proceso, en la práctica el timer mismo, esos id de procesos son compartidos entre ambas funciones.

Comment: lo logre colocando lo que me indico  DaxTter77, pero no use una funcion solo declare la variable con "var" timeout y en la función agregar la igualo al input que se llama fechaout, que es el que tiene en principio el reloj corriendo .clearTimeout(timeout);
 fechaout = timeout;.

Comment: Ahora el problema es que paso el valor por ajax, de fechaout a otro archivo php para que haga la inserción pero me da error en el formato

Comment: Perdon, en el archivo de recepción php tengo lo siguiente                 
$fechaout = $_POST['fechaout'];                                                                                          $fechaout = date_create($fechaout);
$fechaout = $fechaout->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // me da error en el formato que le doy a los datos que llegan desde ajax

Comment: @Julio Entiendo que ese es un tema entre el formato que envías y el formato que espera date de php https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.format.php

Comment: Consulta, porque la función imprime el '0', si ya la primera sentencia indica "tiempo.innerText = i++;"?. No logro despejar mi duda.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que sería mejor usar `setInterval` para evitar tener que crear un `setTimeout` cada segundo. Además, yo crearía una función para obtener el tiempo y otra para mostrarlo, por claridad:

```js
function calculaHora(){
    const momentoActual = new Date()
    const dia = (momentoActual.getDate() < 10 ? '0': '') + momentoActual.getDate()
    const año = momentoActual.getFullYear()
    const mes = (momentoActual.getMonth() < 10 ? '0': '') + momentoActual.getMonth()
    const hora = (momentoActual.getHours() < 10 ? '0': '') + momentoActual.getHours()
    const minuto = (momentoActual.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0': '') + momentoActual.getMinutes()
    const segundo = (momentoActual.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0': '') + momentoActual.getSeconds()
    return `${año}-${mes}-${dia} ${hora}:${minuto}:${segundo}`;
}

const elemento=document.getElementById('fechaout');

const timer = setInterval(()=> {
  elemento.value = calculaHora();
},1000);

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('Parando reloj');
  clearInterval(timer);
});
```

```html
<input id="fechaout" />
<button>Parar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de detenerlo podría ser así

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var timeout; //Crea la variable a fuera de la función para hacerla global
function mueveReloj(){
    momentoActual = new Date()
    dia = momentoActual.getDate()
    año = momentoActual.getFullYear()
    mes = momentoActual.getMonth()
    hora = momentoActual.getHours()
    minuto = momentoActual.getMinutes()
    segundo = momentoActual.getSeconds()

    if (segundo < 10 ){
      segundo = "0" + segundo
    }
     if (minuto < 10 ){
      minuto = "0" + minuto
    }
     if (mes < 10 ){
      mes = "0" + mes
    }
     if (hora < 10 ){
      hora = "0" + hora
    }



    horaImprimible = año + "-" + mes + "-" + dia + "  " + hora + ":" + minuto + ":" + segundo

    document.getElementById('fechaout').value = horaImprimible

    timeout = setTimeout("mueveReloj()",1000);//Guardarlo en una variable
}
</script>///
```

```
function detenerTimeout(){
  clearTimeout(timeout);
}
```

Intentalo de esa manera, se supone que estamos es guardando ese `timeout` en una variable para que quede registrado y de esta manera poderlo detener, alguna duda o sugerencia me la comentas, espero que te sirva, saludos!!

Comment: No funciona, agregue la variable timeout y luego la escribo como  var timeout para que fuera de ambito global pero dentro de  la funcion agregar() llamo la funcion   detenerTimeout()  y no funciona